# SlidesJS slideshow covers html content when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently using SlidesJS to have a slideshow on a webpage in which I have a fixed header (fixed to the top of the page while you scroll). The problem is when I scroll to the bottom of the page, the slideshow stays over the header and covers it.

[image]

Is there a way to make it go under the header while scrolling or make the header always stay over everything (through css, maybe)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use z-index in css to put the header on top.

```
#header {
   z-index: 10;
}
#imageSlider {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice I had not set 'position:relative' on the css for the imageSlider, and therefore z-index wouldn't work.